# Выделение памяти в С++ методами C

Tags: c, c++

Я сейчас пишу код программы на C++, используя приемы С - так привычнее. То есть код очень близок к C программе, но собирается C++ компилятором. В частности, память под структуры выделяю функциями malloc, free вместо new, delete. Насколько это правильно и безопасно?

```
// Это C++

struct P { ... };

P *p = (P *)malloc(sizeof(P));

free(p);
```

Comment: Вы ведь понимаете что это всего лишь скрипт. И нормальное решение может быть описано макро и использовано. Юзать хип - это бред, вообще он ошибка в NT. Есть ядерные сервисы (например, NtAllocateVirtualMemory) - оберните их в обёртки и используйте.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Отлчия malloc/free от new/delete:

- new/delete вызывает деструкторы, а malloc/free нет;
- new/delete знает размер класса(меньше вероятность ошибиться), а malloc/free нет;
- new/delete умеет аллоцировать массивы и при уничтожении вызывать деструкторы каждого элемента массива, а malloc/free нет;

Плюс к этому, раз уж есть с++ под рукой и нужны указатели на объекты, то почему бы не воспользоваться [идиомами](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) auto_ptr, smart_ptr, weak_ptr в подходящих случаях и забыть про геморой с кучей повторов free(p), часть из которых легко упустить из виду.

Answer (score 6):

Если в структуре применяется ООП, так делать нельзя.

Если нет, то дело обстоит так:

- new вычисляет размер структуры автоматически. malloc'у нужен sizeof и т.д.
- malloc возвращает void * и надо обязательно делать преобразование типа. Не ня.
- new автоматом вызывает конструктор (если имеется), delete - деструктор (аналогично, если есть). malloc/free просто оперирует с кусками памяти кучи. Выделяет/освобождает.
- delete может быть перегружен. free - неа. Как и new/malloc.
- new генерирует исключение, если памяти маловато, а malloc просто вернёт пустой указатель.
- Для массивов new требует количество элементов, а malloc - количество памяти, в котором можно случайно ошибиться.
- Однако, у new/delete нет такого оператора, аналогичного функции realloc.
- new - оператор, free - функция =) Ну, это так, для полноты.

Если вас всё это устраивает - пользуйтесь =)

Answer (score 2):

При использовании malloc будут серьёзные побочные эффекты. У вас запросто может сломать что-нибудь внутри реализации ООП C++.. например, могут не работать виртуальные методы. При сборке разными компиляторами и с разными ключами будут вылезать разные косяки. Так что даже не смотрите в сторону malloc/free :)

Comment: Это правда, или прикол? Как так...

Answer (score 1):

Так ведь при malloc() выделится область памяти и вернется указатель, конструктор не вызовется. Пользуйтесь средствами С++ и не мешайте их с C.

Answer (score 1):

Если выделяете память под объект, надо пользовать только new - delete.
Если под  что-то  совместимое с С (структуры , массивы переменных встроенных типов, указателей и т.д.), то можно пользоваться и тем, и другим.

Answer (score 1):

А еще желательно не забыть, какой указатель был инициализирован через new, а какой - через malloc, дабы впоследствии не освобождать память, выделенную new, через free, а ту, что через malloc, соответственно через delete (не говоря уже о массивах). А еще не стоит забывать о том, что после освобождения памяти сами указатели не удаляются, а так и остаются "висеть" в Вашем коде, и уж точно - не к добру; совет, не терять их из виду.

Answer (score 0):

Это не правильно, если вы используете C++, т.к. он заточен на структуры данных.
Правильно писать либо на C++, либо на C. 
В случае, если вы хотите использовать malloc и free, правильно перегружать операторы New, Delete.

В целом, какая разница, какие библиотеки использовать? Если вы пишете хороший код, то нет никакой разницы.

Comment: <i>В случае, если вы хотите использовать malloc и free</i><p>
!?
А кто мешает написать:
<pre>class my_x{...};
...
void\* temp_mem = malloc(sizeof(my_x)); // выделим память откуда нам надо.
my_x\* my_obj= new(temp_mem)my_x; // используем размещающий оператор new</pre>
Правда, деструктор придется вызывать вручную (!?)
<i>операторы New, Delete.</i><p>
Идея не супер - есть много подводных камней.