# Есть ли разница в скорости работы malloc и new

Tags: c++

Я привык для массивов и структур использовать `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`, `free`, а для классов `new` и `delete`.

Если смотреть с точки производительности, что работает быстрее? Ведь если подумать, то `new` и `delete` тоже вызывают `ma/ca/re/alloc` и `free`?

> Вопрос не связан с выделением памяти [c](/questions/tagged/c)/[c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). В вопросе явно говорится о скорости работы, но никак не о способе выделения памяти.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выделение памяти в С++ методами C](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1684/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%a1-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-c)

Comment: По любому  new и, delete лучше использовать. Можно поймать исключение. обработать в случаи неудачи. устанавливать другое исключение  функцией std::set_new_handler(new_handler);

Comment: @ARHovsepyan: это понятно, но вопрос о скорости а не безопасности.

Comment: Вы задаётесь неправильным вопросом. Если вам нужно ускорить работу приложения, то «заменить везде `new` на `malloc`» никогда не является правильным решением. Правильный вопрос — в чём _отличие_ между этими двумя вещами.

Comment: А если вам нужна скорость, пользуйтесь кастомным аллокатором. Ему не нужно быть потокобезопасным, например.

Comment: @Yami, понятно, что скорость   будет незначительно больше, а я  о том, что  не стоит  использовать  то, что по возможностьм и безопасности уступает, когда разница по времени максимально близка к нулю

Comment: Не мешайте в одной программе два разных способа выделения памяти. Зашьетесь. Прежде чем гоняться за 0.01%, погоняйтесь лучше за процентами, уменьшая количество выделений памяти вообще, или за десятками, поменяв алгоритм :)

Answer (score 6):

По стандарту `new` бросает исключения (если это они не отключены глобально и если это не специальная версия без исключений), а значит потенциально медленнее. На практике вы вряд ли заметите разницу, использование `malloc` вместо `new` - классическая преждевременная оптимизация. В любом случае стандартный `malloc` - тоже обычно не самое быстрое решение (есть TCmalloc, например), а реальное падение производительности на выделении памяти обычно означает неудачную архитектуру. Кроме того, `operator new` можно переопределить глобально через тот же `malloc` или другим способом.

Answer (score 2):

Так напишите простенький бенчмарк:

```
auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  p = (char*)malloc(1024);
  free(p);
}
auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

std::cout << "malloc + free: " << (end - start).count() << std::endl;

start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  p = new char [1024];
  delete[] p;
}
end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

std::cout << "new[] + delete[]: " << (end - start).count() << std::endl;
```

На моей машине выдаёт что-то типа

```
malloc + free: 442622446
new[] + delete[]: 468322639
```

То есть, если `new` и медленнее, то не намного.