# std::vector из std::mutex. Как реализовать

Tags: c++, многопоточность, mutex

Нужно сделать вектор со структурой, содержащей вектор из структур, содержащих мьютекс.

Кусок кода, отвечающий за работу с мьютексом

```
struct CommandQueue_leaf {
    struct MyMessen mes;
    unsigned char status;
};


struct MutexList {
    std::string text;
    std::mutex mutex;
};


struct CommandQueue {
    std::vector<struct CommandQueue_leaf> mes;
    std::vector<struct MutexList> UsedFiles;
};


...


// Главный цикл  


struct CommandQueue* cm...

struct MutexList* res = (struct MutexList*)malloc(sizeof * res);
res->text = str;
cm->UsedFiles.push_back(*res);
free(res);

...

// В потоках
cm->UsedFiles[mutexnum].mutex.lock();
cm->UsedFiles[mutexnum].mutex.unlock();


...

// Главный цикл   
//Очистка
cm->mes.clear();
cm->UsedFiles.clear();
```

При компиляции пишет:

> Ошибка    C2280:  "MutexList::MutexList(const MutexList &)": предпринята
>   попытка ссылки на удаленную функцию   Server

Comment: Ссылка на весь код: https://pastebin.com/0erYP5zi (Lasciate ogni speranza, voi ch’entrate)

Comment: Зачем вы делаете malloc?

Comment: @PavelMayorov для выделения памяти под структуру, которую после копирую в вектор

Comment: А зачем вам как-то отдельно выделять под нее память? Чем вас не устроила переменная на стеке?

Comment: Кстати, вы же в курсе, что `malloc` оставляет объекты в недопустимом состоянии, и вам нужно вызвать конструктор перед тем как их использовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мьютекс невозможно ни скопировать, ни даже перенести. Поэтому вам надо использовать какой-нибудь перемещаемых контейнер для мьютекса, например `std::unique_ptr`, и переносить его через `std::move`. И да, забудьте про `malloc` - вызовов этой функции в плюсовом коде быть не должно. В данном случае, указатели вообще не требуются:

```
struct MutexList {
    std::string text;
    std::unique_ptr<std::mutex> mutex;
};

// ...

MutexList res;
res.text = ...;
res.mutex = std::make_unique<std::mutex>();
cm->UsedFiles.push_back(std::move(res));

// ...

cm->UsedFiles[mutexnum].mutex->lock();
```

Comment: Почему malloc лучше new?

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG где я такое писал?

Comment: Тогда не совсем понятно...   У меня в том месте должно набиваться дофига std::mutexов, а то, что вы предложили (без указателей) даже не знаю... Но главное: как теперь lock() вызвать

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG не могли бы вы более точно описать свои затруднения? И при чём тут дофига мьютексов?

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG кстати, чем вас не устроил вызов `lock()` из моего ответа?

Comment: Тем, что VS пишет, мол, нельза вызывать mutex из указателя

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG не должна студия такого писать

Comment: Сорри, разобрался - просто два раза точку поставил :)

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG `new` лучше тем, что он вызывает конструктор, в отличие от `malloc`. Без этого классы вроде `std::string` не будут работать. Но ни то, ни другое лучше не использовать без необходимости.

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG почитайте [старый вопросик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1684/176217) от нашего КМ.